# Nothing happens on click "edit" or "delete" buttons on user flagged comments page

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/users/:userId/post-comments?state=flagged

> [image]

On click there are no errors/logs in console/network requests.

Comment: For me, the delete link works (on my own comments), but the edit doesn't.